# Transpile dependency when running tests with Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I added a dependency on tiptap-vuetify to my Vue app which in turn added transitive dependencies on 19 other modules. After adding it, I ran my tests and got the following error

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at node_modules/tiptap-vuetify/dist/bundle-umd.js:1:112
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/tiptap-vuetify/dist/bundle-umd.js:1:2)
```

So it seems that tiptap-vuetify contains code that Jest needs to transpile. According to the [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring) adding the following to `jest.config.js` should fix the problem if the untranspiled code is in either tiptap or tiptap-vuetify

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
  "node_modules/(?!(tiptap-vuetify|tiptap)/)"
]
```

But it didn't make any difference. I added the following instead:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/tiptap.*']
```

and the problem no longer occurs, but I think I may be transpiling my entire dependency tree, because the tests take much longer to run now. Is there a better way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tiptap-vuetify` isn't the actual module that is causing the error, despite the misleading stacktrace.

The error most likely comes from `vuetify`, as shown in the `Details` output of the Jest error:

```
    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    //...

    Details:
                                                         
    /Users/tony/src/tmp/vue2-vuetify-test/node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './components';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      11 | <script>
      12 | // import the component and the necessary extensions
    > 13 | import { TiptapVuetify, Heading, Bold, Italic, Strike, Underline, Code, Paragraph, BulletList, OrderedList, ListItem, Link, Blockquote, HardBreak, HorizontalRule, History } from 'tiptap-vuetify'
         | ^
      14 |
      15 | export default {
      16 |   // specify TiptapVuetify component in "components"

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at node_modules/tiptap-vuetify/dist/bundle-umd.js:1:201
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/tiptap-vuetify/dist/bundle-umd.js:1:429)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/MyTipTap.vue:13:1)
```

Make sure your [`transformIgnorePatterns` excludes `vuetify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55073524/6277151) to ensure it gets transpiled:

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!vuetify)'],
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, but I don't understand how tiptap-vuetify is not the cause of the problem, given that this error occurs when I have Vuetify and tiptap-vuetify installed, but does not occur when only Vuetify is installed?